# Iterate through the json and parse the result to variable in scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing

I am a beginner in scala. I have a JSON file and I need to parse the content in scala.
The JSON is given below.

```
{
  "filmdetails": [
    {
      "country": "US",
      "details": {
        "properties": "category, director, actor, actress, relased_date, collection",
        "category": "action",
        "director": "michel_bay",
        "actor": "rock",
        "actress": "ruth_jackson",
        "release_date": "2016",
        "collection": "200_billion"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

First, I need to check for the country then I need to iterate the properties for each detail ("category, director, actor, actress, release_date, collection").
Then take each property and check, if it is present in key then print its value.

I have tried with for each but couldn't find luck.

Comment: i try to read a json and parse it using json4s library. i would like to know how to iterate each key and then take its value.

Comment: What kind of iteration do you mean? At some specific level of nesting or visiting all nodes of JSON AST?

Comment: Since this a particular json i need to take values of properties first. so that will be a list of strings. Then i need to take each string and check that is a key or not. If key then need to take its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this like shown below. I have used `jobSession` and using that

```
val jobContext = jobSession.getJobContext()
val list_Properties = List(jobContext.getValue("properties"))
```

So we got the details like "category, director, actor, actress, relased_date, collection".

Then I used the `foldLeft` method to get values as shown below.

```
val filmDetails = list_Properties .foldLeft(List[String]())((acc, eachConf) =>
      { acc.+:(jobContext.getValue(s"$eachConf")) })

print(filmDetails)
```